# Why do I get this "The name `length' does not exist in the current context" when it is used?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    bool loop1 = true; 
    while(loop1)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the base length");
      try
      {
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Entry: "+ex.Message);
        continue;
      }

      Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the perpendicular height");
      try
      {
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Entry: "+ex.Message);
      }
      Console.WriteLine(area(length,height));
    }
  }

  static int area(int length, int height)
  {
    return length * height/2;
  }
}
```

I get the error

> exit status 1
>   main.cs(28,40): error CS0103: The name `length' does not exist in the current context
>   main.cs(28,47): error CS0103: The name`height' does not exist in the current context
>   Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: Do you know what a scope in C# is (the curly braces `{`,`}`)?

Comment: Because your `length` and `height` variables are defined within the scope of the `try` block.

Comment: See this tutorial about variable scopes, for example: https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-24-understanding-variable-scope

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring your variables inside the try, you need to move the declaration outside the try statement.  I think this will fix it.  Plus your declaring length twice, I think that was a typo and should have been height.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
              int length = 0;
              int height = 0;

              bool loop1 = true; 
              while(loop1)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the base length");
                try
                {
                     length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Entry: "+ex.Message);
                    continue;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the perpendicular height");
                try
                {
                     height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Entry: "+ex.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(area(length,height));
            }// end while
      }// end main 
            static int area(int length, int height)
              {
                return length * height/2;
              }
}// end calss
```

Comment: this gives me an:


exit status 1
main.cs(31,47): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `height'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: It looks like (not sure if you can post what line the error is on)  You have to redo how your code is working.  This is a different issue then your original request/issue.  You are doing try/catch and then continuing.  If is getting to the call of area(length, height)   and you never set the height (because you had an error) but you continued the variable is never set.  I updated the code to set a default of 0 to each variable.  You shouldnt get that error anymore, but you will probably get a divide by 0 error if they dont have propert height value and you continue

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the local variables `length` inside your try blocks; they only exist in that scope. Once execution leaves the try block, it doesn't exist anymore.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx for more information about how scoping works in C#.

More specifically, when you call `Console.WriteLine(area(length,height));`, the variables `length` and `height` that you are trying to pass into the method do not exist in that scope. Declare them in that scope, rather than inside the try blocks.

Comment: I added this but it tells me that int is unexpected :/

static int area (int length, int height)
       {
          length* height /2;
       }

Comment: @Nathan I'm not sure what you mean by that. Does the update to may answer help at all?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is your defined variable `int length` is scoped inside curly braces `{ }`. So the variable is only available inside the brace it is defined.

To be able to access the variable as you want, you have to define length at the start outside try block.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically addressing the "Use of unassigned local variable 'height'" message...

This normally happens if you try to reference a variable that has never been assigned a value.  Something like the following will trigger this error message:

```
int x;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Does the "Use of unassigned local variable 'height'" message happen when you enter invalid input that can't be cast as an integer?  Entering something like "x" or "1.5" for length will cause the `Convert.ToInt32()` call to throw an exception, meaning that your `length` variable will not have anything assigned to it when the call to `Console.WriteLine(area(length,height));` happens later.

You can fix/prevent this by initializing your variable when they are declared:

```
int length = 0;
int height = 0;
```

Now the variables are initialized and you won't see the "Use of unassigned local variable 'height'" message.  You'll probably get `0` as your calculated area, but that's a different issue entirely. :)

I'm making assumptions about your input, but that's the only way I can think of to replicate the error you're seeing.

Comment: For the record, I think this post was changed twice while I was typing... :)